# Properly right-aligning Hebrew quotation at the end of a sentence on a new line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, languages, polyglossia, right-to-left

I'm having a minor issue with Hebrew quotations in a document I'm typesetting. I have quotations from the bible in the form "Book chapter:verse: Hebrew text". When the Hebrew text continues on the next line, it is left-aligned, while I want it to be right-aligned.

Using `\flushright` is not an option, as the bible reference should still be left-aligned. Using `\hfill` is not an option, because I don't know where the line break occurs.

Please see the MWE below. The result should be either as the first example, but with the second line right-aligned, or, equivalently, as the second example, but with the first line justified.

When a paragraph is only one line long, it should be left-aligned.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ezra SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ez}{\hebrewfont}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

Nehemia 4:8b--c: \RL{\ez{אל־תיראו מפניהם את־אדני הגדול והנורא זכרו והלחמו על־אחיכם בניכם ובנתיכם נשיכם ובתיכם}}

\flushright{Nehemia 4:8b--c: \RL{\ez{אל־תיראו מפניהם את־אדני הגדול והנורא זכרו והלחמו על־אחיכם בניכם ובנתיכם נשיכם ובתיכם}}}

\end{document}
```

(Compile with XeLaTeX. Requires the [Ezra SIL font](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=EzraSIL_Home)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Script=Hebrew]{SBL BibLit}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newenvironment{RTLpar}{%
  \par\ignorespaces
  \leftskip=0pt plus .5fil%
  \rightskip=0pt plus -.5fil%
  \parfillskip=0pt plus .5fil%
}{\par}
\newbox\linebox
\newcount\linecount
\def\countparlines{%
  \setbox\linebox\lastbox
  \ifvoid\linebox
  \else
    \global\advance\linecount 1%
    \unskip\unpenalty
    {\countparlines}%
  \fi}
\def\rtlpar#1{%
  \vskip-\baselineskip % This is a hack, but I don't know the proper solution
  \global\linecount=0%
  \vbox{#1\par\countparlines}%
  \ifnum\linecount>1
    \begingroup
    \leftskip=0pt plus .5fil%
    \rightskip=0pt plus -.5fil%
    \parfillskip=0pt plus .5fil%
    #1\par
    \endgroup
  \else
    #1\par
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{RTLpar}
  Nehemiah 4:8b--c: \texthebrew{אל־תיראו מפניהם את־אדני הגדול והנורא זכרו
  והלחמו על־אחיכם בניכם ובנתיכם נשיכם ובתיכם}
\end{RTLpar}
\rtlpar{Nehemiah 4:8b--c: \texthebrew{אל־תיראו מפניהם את־אדני הגדול והנורא זכרו
והלחמו על־אחיכם בניכם ובנתיכם נשיכם ובתיכם}}
\rtlpar{Nehemiah 4:8a: \texthebrew{וארא ואקום ואמר אל־החרים ואל־הסגנים ואל
יתר העם}}
\begin{quote}
  \begin{hebrew}
    אל־תיראו מפניהם את־אדני הגדול והנורא זכרו והלחמו על־אחיכם בניכם ובנתיכם
    נשיכם ובתיכם (\textenglish{Nehemiah 4:8b--c})
  \end{hebrew}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. I wasn't clear in my original question, but is it also possible to have the paragraph left-aligned when it consists of only one line?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I've updated my example with a new `rtlpar{}` macro that tests if the paragraph is more than one line in length. This is getting beyond my TeX expertise, so there might be some problems. Perhaps others can comment.